# Angular shows wrong html

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and trying out a small application.
Here are my various files:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";  

@Component({
  selector: 'pm-root',
  template:`
  <div> <h1> {{pageTitle}}</h1>
  <div> My First Component</div>
  </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent{
  pageTitle: string = "Acme product management";
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ApmNew</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <pm-root></pm-root>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I am running it it show me the default angular page which is

[image: Default angular page]

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';


platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

This page is nothing but **app.component.html**
In want **index.html** to be shown. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's in your `main.ts` ?

Comment: added main.ts. Please check

Comment: Are you sure you're starting the same project as the one you edited ?

Comment: Yes, is there any way to verify ?